# Markov Chain expressed in Density Matrix formalism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, probability

Suppose we have two states of a system where I tell you that there is a probability $p_1$ of being in state $1$, and probability $p_2$ of being in state $2$. The total state can be written as a vector in $L^1$ normed space:

$$p=\begin{pmatrix}p_1 \\ p_2 \end{pmatrix}, ||p||=p_1+p_2=1$$

If we define a transition matrix for a Markov process:

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}t_{11}&t_{12} \\ t_{21}&t_{22}\end{pmatrix}$$

Then the next state would be:

$$p'=Tp=\begin{pmatrix}t_{11}p_1+t_{12}p_2 \\ t_{21}p_1+t_{22}p_2\end{pmatrix}$$

Now my understanding of density matrices and quantum mechanics is that it should contain classical probability theory in addition to strictly quantum phenomena.

Classical probabilities in the density matrix formalism are mapped as:

$$p=\begin{pmatrix}p_1 \\ p_2 \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \rho=\begin{pmatrix}p_1&0 \\ 0&p_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

And I want to obtain:

$$p'=\begin{pmatrix}t_{11}p_1+t_{12}p_2 \\ t_{21}p_1+t_{22}p_2\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \rho'=\begin{pmatrix}t_{11}p_1+t_{12}p_2&0 \\ 0&t_{21}p_1+t_{22}p_2\end{pmatrix}$$

**My attempt:**

Define an operator $U$ such that:

$$\rho'=U\rho U^\dagger$$
$$\implies \begin{pmatrix}t_{11}p_1+t_{12}p_2&0 \\ 0&t_{21}p_1+t_{22}p_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}u_{11}&u_{12} \\ u_{21}&u_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p_1&0 \\ 0&p_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_{11}^*&u_{21}^* \\ u_{12}^*&u_{22}^*\end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix}|u_{11}|^2p_1+|u_{12}|^2p_2&u_{11}u_{21}^*p_1+u_{12}u_{22}^*p_2 \\ 
u_{21}u_{11}^*p_1+u_{12}^*u_{22}p_2 & |u_{21}|^2p_1+|u_{22}|^2p_2  \end{pmatrix}$$

Evidently, $|u_{ij}|^2=t_{ij}$, but the off diagonal terms aren't easily made zero, (I've wrestled with the algebra and applied all the proper normalizations of probability theory).

What would be the correct way to apply a Markov process in the density matrix formalism? It seems really basic and something that this formalism should be able to naturally handle.

Comment: You may want consider asking this type of questions at https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Didn't know that was a thing. Is there a quick way to repost or share it there?

Edit: Nevermind, just copy-pasted

Comment: I suggest to copy-paste the question to QC and link to this one. Meanwhile, I'll flag this for a moderator as "on hold".

Comment: This question has been [reposted to another SE site](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1895).

Comment: @rob: Why on earth would this not be about physics? It is about evolution of quantum systems!

Comment: @ConnorDolan You are looking for completely positive map.  Unitary evolution will not yield that.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch The OP posted this to another site after being recommended to move it there. It's not so much that it's off-topic here as it is more on-topic there. See the [cross-posting policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/380389) on meta.

Comment: @Chris I disagree. It is about physics, not about quantum computers. (Note that on QC.SE, it has been asked what it has to do with QC.) It is about how to describe the evolution of a quantum system.  This is as much physics as it gets. Or would you only consider questions about continuous-time evolution and pure states on topic?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Whether you agree or not, the OP made the decision to move it, not the moderator. If it gets closed as off-topic at QC.SE, I'm sure it will be reopened here.

Comment: @Chris Then it should be closed as duplicate or sth. else. This way, the close reason makes the impression that such questions are off-topic here, which they aren't.  (Or are such questions supposed to be close **as off-topic**? In case, I'd be grateful for a reference.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch The duplicate close reason is not allowed for posts on different sites. The other options are "too broad," "unclear what you're asking," or "primarily opinion-based," none of which remotely fit. Rob picked "custom reason," which puts "off-topic" in the banner and adds the custom reason as a comment.

Comment: @Chris But there is no custom reason.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Sure there is- "This question has been reposted to another SE site."

Comment: @Chris Oh, as a comment.  I thought user-defined close reasons appear next to the close reason.  Don't they?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch No. With custom close reasons it always looks like it does here- just "off-topic" with no clarification.